# How to apply condition in django admin form?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have models like this in Django:

```
from django.db import models


class Navigation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=1)
    is_premium = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question


class QuestionType(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField(Question)
    question_types = (
                      (1, 'Multiple Choice'),
                      (2, 'Text Answer')
                      )
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=question_types, verbose_name="Select Question Type")


class Category(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField(Question)
    navigation = models.OneToOneField(Navigation)
    choices_options = (
        (1, 'Begineer'),
        (2, 'Intermediate'),
        (3, 'Expert')
    )

    choices = models.IntegerField(choices=choices_options, verbose_name="Select level")


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField(Question)
    choice = models.OneToOneField(Choice)
```

And I have admin.py like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from quiz.models import Navigation, Category, Question, Choice, Answer, QuestionType



class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3


class CategoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Category


class QuestionTypeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = QuestionType

class AnswerInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Answer

class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
    (None,
    {'fields': ['question']}),
    ('Date information', {'fields': ['publication_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline, CategoryInline, AnswerInline, QuestionTypeInline]

    # Display two headings while displaying all the questions
    list_display = ('question', 'publication_date')

    # Add filter option
    list_filter = ['publication_date']

    # Add search capability
    search_fields = ['question']

    # Show the latest elements by default
    date_hierarchy = 'publication_date'




admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)
admin.site.register(Navigation)
```

There would be two types of questions: `Multiple Choice questions, text based questions.` So while creating the question, I want to show the choices if the user select multiple choice question and show the text based one input if the user select text based question. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So while creating the question, I want to show the choices if the user
>   select multiple choice question and show the text based one input if
>   the user select text based question. How can I do that?

You need some javascript for that since that's happening during the creation.

Follow these steps:

1. In QuestionAdmin change the create template
2. In this new template add some javascript to hide both fields
3. Add the javascript to show the appropriate field depending on the selection

If someone doesn't have javascript working, their would see both fields.

Show your code if you struggle with one of these steps.

Comment: Yeah but there are lots of templates available here in contrib/admin/templates/admin/. Which template should I edit for this?You can also point me to some tutorial regarding this. Cheers

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe it's the change_form.html one. It's easy to test. Write this: add_form_template = "admin/change_form.html" in the QuestionAdmin class. If the admin page is unchanged, that's the good one. Then, replace this with your custom template that extends "admin/change_form.html"...